# awk, skip current rule upon sanity check

Tags: if-statement, awk, skip

How to skip current awk rule when its sanity check failed?

```
{
  if (not_applicable) skip;
  if (not_sanity_check2) skip;
  if (not_sanity_check3) skip;
  # the rest of the actions
}
```

IMHO, it's much cleaner to write code this way than,

```
{
  if (!not_applicable) {
    if (!not_sanity_check2) {
      if (!not_sanity_check3) {
      # the rest of the actions
      }
    }
  }
}

1;
```

I need to skip the current rule because I have a catch all rule at the end.

UPDATE, the case I'm trying to solve.

There is multiple match point in a file that I want to match & alter, however, there's no other obvious sign for me to match what I want.
hmmm..., let me simplify it this way, I want to match & alter the first match and skip the rest of the matches and print them as-is.

Comment: How about `if (applicable) do;` which of course you can get to with a double negative: `if !(not_applicable) do;`

Comment: @dawg, see my nested if example. Normally sanity check will check and skip multiple conditions. The problem I want to avoid is the ***nested if*** due to multiple sanity check conditions.

Comment: The two do not seem to be equivalent. The first example, all three are independent; the second example, `# the rest of the rules` is dependent on all three conditions being True.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output and actual workable code that demonstrates your needs so we can best help you. It's really not clear from your question what it is you're trying to do (or if by `skip` you mean `next` in that first code block). It's also not clear what you mean by a `rule` - an awk script is made up of `condition  { action }` statements, is either "condition" or "action" (or either?) a "rule" to you or is it the whole `condition  { action }` statement that's a "rule" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your requirement, you are looking for `if`, `else if` here. Also you could use [`switch`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Switch-Statement.html) case available in newer version of `gawk` packages too.

Let's take an example of a Input_file here:

```
cat Input_file
9
29
```

Following is the `awk` code here:

`awk -v var="10" '{if($0<var){print "Line " FNR " is less than var"} else if($0>var){print "Line " FNR " is greater than var"}}' Input_file`

This will print as follows:

```
Line 1 is less than var
Line 2 isgreater than var
```

So if you see code carefully its checking:

- First condition if current line is less than var then it will be executed in `if` block.
- Second condition in else if block, if current line is greater than var then print it there.

Comment: Sorry, you might not have catch my update of _"I need to skip the current rule because I have a catch all rule at the end"_. I.e., I don't want to skip to next line but skip to next matching rule.

Comment: @xpt, Could you please try my updated code and do let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Yeah. I guess that's the only way to go, and there is no "cleaner" solution. thanks!

Comment: @xpt, Also you could use `switch` case available in newer version of `gawk` packages too. Here is the documentation link for same https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Switch-Statement.html

Comment: Yep, saw that in https://opensource.com/article/19/12/control-awk-script. thx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do but if I focus on just that last sentence in your question of `I want to match & alter the first match and skip the rest of the matches and print them as-is.` ... is this what you're trying to do?

```
{ s=1 }
s && /abc/ { $0="uvw"; s=0 }
s && /def/ { $0="xyz"; s=0 }
{ print }
```

e.g. to borrow [@Ravinder's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68122748/1745001):

```
$ cat Input_file
9
29
```

```
$ awk -v var='10' '
    { s=1 }
    s && ($0<var) { $0="Line " FNR " is less than var";    s=0 }
    s && ($0>var) { $0="Line " FNR " is greater than var"; s=0 }
    { print }
' Input_file
Line 1 is less than var
Line 2 is greater than var
```

I used the boolean flag variable name `s` for `sane` as you also mentioned something in your question about the conditions tested being sanity checks so each condition can be read as `is the input sane so far and this next condition is true?`.

Comment: The `{ s=1 }` must be in `BEGIN`, else it'll get reset every time, right?

Comment: It's supposed to be set at the start of processing each line of input, assuming you want to run your sanity checks on each line of input independently of each other. Again, though, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do so I'm just guessing at that. If you edit your question to show us a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that would be a big help.